# How to add one hardcoded selection option in ng-options which is filling by $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add one extra hard coded option in ng-options. This selection option is filling dynamically. But I want to add one option more.

**HTML**

```
    <div>
    <label>Group by:</label>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="group_by" name="group_by" ng-change="update()" ng-options="value.Name for value in groups">     
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angularjs**

```
$http.get($http, $scope)
.scucess(function(response){
    $scope.metrics =response.data;      
    $scope.metric = obj[0];
})
```

**Selection will look like**

```
Option1 =>Hard coded option  
Option2 => Dynamic options  
Option3 => ""  
Option4 => ""  
Option5  => ""  
.......  
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more `<option> tag` under your `<select>` like this :

```
<select ng-model="model.id" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users">
    <option value="">-- select user --</option>
</select>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/74D8PQyID59yFwngqCrI?p=preview)